# PDF Parser Library for Actionscript3/Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I’m working on AIR application,

my problem is I have to extract text, images or any other objects from the PDF file and convert in to text or image controls respectively in my application, and

then I have to add the controls to a container at the same positions (same x, y, width, height) like in PDF file.

Also I have to display the PDF page thumbnail images on a list.

Is there any better option for parsing PDF files and generating thumbnail from PDF pages without using any server side scripting?

Is there any opensource lib available other than `Alive PDF`?. In Alive PDF hard to parse  my requirement.

your bit help also welcome.

Comment: I would definitely use a server side scripting for this.  I don't know of any other lib that would help you out and even with Alive PDF I would still chose server side if available.

Comment: Thanks. If i prefer server script means which lib better fit for my requirement let me know.

Comment: There I don't have a good answer for you.  This might point you in right direction http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php

Comment: Have u heard about PDFJS?

Comment: @dev ya PDFJS already heard about it. unfortunately i am looking for actionscript version.

Answer (score 1):

You should try PurePdf : http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/

You can also use an external app and launch it through Air NativeProcess class

Answer (score 0):

http://avinashkaza.com/blog/?p=1

The application class, SamplePDFLoader.mxml calls the IFrame component and loads PDF file on creation complete. Also this class calls a JavaScript function through external interface class to print the PDF when user clicks on the button.
The IFrame.mxml component, this component makes calls to the wrapper html’s javascript functions to load the PDF into div tag, move the PDF with the IFrame component container etc..

http://www.devaldi.com/?p=212

Comment: Thanks i am asking how to parse PDF file instead of load/view pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some budget, I can strongly recommend the Java PDF Library from http://bfo.com 
We are using it in a large project and the results are really good.